# Openssl and Boost.Asio compile error

Tags: c++, openssl, boost-asio

I am trying to run the Boost.Asio SSL example but I got a lots of 
Undefined reference to ... :

```
undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
...
```

I've already link my libs (ssl and crypto) after the file name when compiling.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a linker error and has been asked many times. Will find dupe

Comment: Also check the order of the arguments (libraries go _after_ your object files)!

Comment: @sehe Hi, I set my code::block to compile as follow : `$compiler $includes -c $file -o $object $options`, and nothing changed